# Why is a solution working on windows and not on a mac (different cycle speeds?)?

Tags: spacechem

Is there a differences is the speed at which the cycles are performed on a mac vs. windows. I have been using the steam sync across both platforms and have yet to notice any issues, but I was playing around with other peoples solutions from spacechem.net and they aren't working for me on my mac. One of the solutions mentioned that the cycle output was different on a mac, but I cannot find any documentation or corroborating evidence of such.

Mainly I have noticed that some of the solutions for the fewest symbols/cycles just don't even work on my mac. I rarely get a chance to use windows so I am not able to directly test this.

Comment: whats the assignment? hard to confirm if we dont know what it is.

Comment: it was on multiple assignments that I had noticed on my iPad first in Random Oxides and then in the next level on No Ordinary Headache.

Answer (score 4):

One possible reason for this is that on assignments with randomized inputs (such as Random Oxides and No Ordinary Headache), the pre-determined random order is different on Macs and Windows, likely due to different random-number-generator implementations. Therefore, if critical molecules like nitrogens show up sooner in the Windows sequence than in the Mac sequence, the solution will run faster on Windows than on a Mac.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt there are differences since each cycle is a single action (i.e., move a single square or perform a single action). At least that's how it is on Windows systems anyways -- not sure why Mac would calculate it differently.

The solutions you are referring to could be based on hidden bonding order.

Comment: well I have noticed the red and blue waldos have a command priority, but I don't think that is different on windows.